# In EE3 can I query the Model service for template info in my template's PHP?

Tags: templates, php, template-scripting, ee3

I want to do something like:

```
$templates = ee( "Model" )->get( "Template" )->all();

//Loop through them
foreach( $templates as $template ) ...
```

But when I try this, it hangs the page/server. Is this not possible in a template?

Comment: This is no answer to your question of course, but you would consume much less resources if you wrap this PHP into plugin.

Comment: Is all you want a list of your templates? Just use the Query module.